# Non-Query storedprocedure in EF core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP.net core and want to create an MVC website that shows the student data and changes their status from out-of-school to new when the user clicks on the change-status button. Below are the classes ,the DB table and SP.

The change status method in contoller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeStatus(long? id)
    {
         if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var students = await _db.Students
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (students == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var Id = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Id",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = student.Id
        };

        _db.Students.FromSqlInterpolated($" EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_changeStatus] @Id = {Id}").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View(student);
    }
```

The Model class:

```
 public class Student
    {
            [Key]
            public Int64 Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Age { get; set; }
    }
```

DBContext:

```
public DbSet<Student> Students{ get; set; }
```

In Database:

Table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL);
```

StoredProcedure:

```
  Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_changeStatus]
    @Id bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    update [dbo].[Students] set [Status] = 'New'
    where Id = @Id;
END
```

Problem:
After clicking  change-status button the SP runs and the status changed in DB table but the error in the following image appears:

[image]

Comment: `FromSqlInterpolated` is trying to execute a **query** - but your `usp_changeStatus` doesn't return a result set (and I'm not suggesting that it should) - so it *isn't* a query; is there perhaps another API that executes non-queries? (this would be trivial with "Dapper", but I'm guessing you don't want to change that)

Comment: (with Dapper: `connection.Execute('usp_changeStatus', new { student.Id }, CommandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` and you're done)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your help, the problem solved using the  "Database.ExecuteSqlCommand" method.